# Removing file path from attachment name when using MailMessage

Tags: c#, asp.net, email

I am trying to send an attachment using MailMessage class.

```
var attachment = new Attachment(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["pathToPDFs"] + pdfItem.Value);
mailMessage.Attachments.Add(attachment);
```

This adds the file as an attachment but when I receive the file on my email the name is

`//Inetpub//Path//To//pdf//name.pdf` it should be just name.pdf.

Where am I going wrong?

`ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["pathToPDFs"]` is set as `C://Inetpub//Path//To//pdf//`
`pdfItem.Value` is name.pdf

Comment: Don't you mean: C:\\inetpub\\path\\to\\pdf\\ ?

Comment: @Jack no my path are // not \\

Comment: @Jack changing the // to \\ fixed the problem. Add an answer and I will accept it.

Comment: Aren't you on a Windows based machine?

Comment: @Sally - answer is below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you receive the e-mail attachment, is it the correct attachment?

Meaning, do you actually get the name.pdf?

Also, your location should be: `C:\\inetpub\\path\\to\\pdf\name.pdf`

Have you tried hard-coding the file location and seeing if that fixes your problem?

Answer (score 1):

I have to confess first, I am guessing.

The constructor may be using the full path as the name. If you set the name property after creating the object if might work.

```
var attachment = new Attachment(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["pathToPDFs"] + pdfItem.Value); 

attachment.Name = pdfItem.Value;

mailMessage.Attachments.Add(attachment);
```

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem, and later on I found that it was because I used the relative path of the file, i.e. ../../name.pdf. If I get the full path to create the attachment, then the attachment file name in the email doesn't contain the path.

```
string full_file_name = Path.GetFullPath("../../name.pdf");
Attachment attachment = new Attachment(full_file_name);
mailMessage.Attachments.Add(attachment);
```